# How can I compute a transition table in R using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering how I can compute a transition table for when new ID's are introduced (+1) and ID's are removed (-1).

For example:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5),
           year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017))

ids <- unique(dt$id)
```

So for the first year (2016), it should be:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
```

and the second year (2017) it should be:

```
0, 0, -1, 0, 0
```

Comment: `dcast(dt, year ~ id, length, fill = 0L)[, lapply(.SD, diff), .SDcols = -"year"]`

Comment: `tt <- table(dt)`; `tt[ , -1] - tt[ , -ncol(tt)]`

Comment: @DavidA Looks answer-worthy. No need for fill=0 with fun=length; also could keep a year col: `dcast(dt, year ~ id, length)[, c(.(year = tail(year, -1)), lapply(.SD, diff)), .SDcols = as.character(ids)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach which uses a *cross join* and *aggregates in a join*. It is essentially equivalent to the `dcast()` and `table()` solutions above but keeps the data in long form:

```
dt[CJ(year = year, id = id, unique = TRUE), on = .(id, year), .N, by = .EACHI][
  , change := N - shift(N), by = id][]
```

> ```
>     id year N change
>  1:  1 2015 1     NA
>  2:  2 2015 1     NA
>  3:  3 2015 1     NA
>  4:  4 2015 0     NA
>  5:  5 2015 0     NA
>  6:  1 2016 1      0
>  7:  2 2016 1      0
>  8:  3 2016 1      0
>  9:  4 2016 1      1
> 10:  5 2016 1      1
> 11:  1 2017 1      0
> 12:  2 2017 1      0
> 13:  3 2017 0     -1
> 14:  4 2017 1      0
> 15:  5 2017 1      0
> ```